# How can I delete and deallocate OVM objects in SystemVerilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I would like to delete an ovm object (and its children) so that I can recreate it with different configs. Is there a way to do this in OVM?

Currently, when I try to create the object a second time with `new`, I get the following VCS runtime error:

`[CLDEXT] Cannot set 'ap' as a child of 'instance', which already has a child by that name.`

I realize that I can simply use a different name to "re-create" the instance, but then I'll still have the old instance sitting around and soaking up memory.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What code gives you the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OVM is just a SystemVerilog library.  That means that all the rules of SystemVerilog apply to OVM.  So, yes, you can use new() with OVM.  Sometimes it's preferable to use the factory, and sometimes it's preferable to use new() (that's a topic for a different discussion).

SystemVerilog does not have a delete operator or a destructor like C++.  Instead, when you are done with an object you just remove all references to it and the garbage collector will clean up the memory.  Here's a quote from the SystemVerilog reference manual (IEEE 1800-2009) section 8.7:

> *SystemVerilog does not require the complex memory allocation and deallocation of C++. Construction of an object is straightforward; and garbage collection, as in Java, is implicit and automatic. There can be no memory leaks or other subtle behaviors, which are so often the bane of C++ programmers.*

It's not entirely true that you cannot have a memory leak.  You can forget to remove all references to an object and the garbage collector will not know to pick it up.  However, you do not have to worry about memory with the same detail as you do in C++.

The particular error you received with id CLDEXT is from ovm_component class. From the message it appears that you attempted to create two components with the same name and the same parent.  Components in OVM are typically static.  That is, you create and elaborate them once, usually at time 0, and don't delete or add components after that.  Because of this model there are no methods in ovm_component to remove child components.  So there really isn't a good way to replace a component once it has been instantiated. By the way, this only applies to components.  Other types of objects can be re-allocated.

If you feel that you need to replace a component with a different one after time 0 you should re-think the architecture of your testbench.  There are probably betters ways to accomplish what you are trying to do without replacing components.

Answer (score 2):

I have only UVM experience but I think OVM is similar. I would have liked to reply to @Victor Lyuboslavsky's comment but I can't add comments.

The issue is with the name 'ap' which evidently has already been used for a child of 'instance'. Use this code instead.

```
static int instNum = 0;
instance_ap = my_ovm_extended_class::type_id::create
                ($sformatf ("ap%0d", instNum), this);
```

The first time an object is created & the handle assigned to 'instance_ap', the object would have the name 'instance.ap0'. The next time the code executes an object called 'instance.ap1', and so on.

As mentioned by other posters this ought to be done only for non-component objects, and components should be static and must be created during/before the build phase & connected to each other during/before the connect phase.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning null to the object before calling new again.

Comment: This is OVM. There is no `new`. Objects are created with a factory like this: `instance_ap = my_ovm_extended_class::type_id::create("ap",this);` This gives the VCS runtime error mentioned above.

Comment: @Victor, I have only UVM experience but I think OVM is similar. The issue is with the name `ap` which evidently has already been used for a child of `instance`. Use this code instead: `static int instNum = 0; instance_ap = my_ovm_extended_class::type_id::create ($sformatf ("ap%0d", instNum), this); instNum++;`. Each time an object is created & assigned to `instance_ap`, the name would be different, `instance.ap0`,`instance.ap1`, etc. As mentioned by others this ought to be done only for non-component objects, and components should be static and must be created during/before the build phase.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I see someone else answer this question, I'd say there is no easy way to deallocate objects in OVM framework.

Comment: objects are deallocated by the garbage collector when they no longer have anything holding a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

OVM testbenches are static and created when the testbench is created.

When the environment class is instantiated, it will call new(create), build, connect, end_of_elaboration, start_of_simulation, run and check on all components.

By the end of the environment build phase all components must be created.

By the end of the environment connect phase all components must have their TLM ports connected.

Because of these requirements, you can not change components (or port connections) except for during the phase.

As part of the static nature of the testbench environment, every component must have a unique get_full_name() response. This is because string lookups are used to identify components in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning an object to null should deallocate memory. If there is no other handle pointing to that memory location, then it should get reclaimed.